# ¿Cómo sumo el precio total de los artículos teniendo repetido un campo?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estas son mis tablas
[image: Tabla "facturas" y "detalle de factura"]

Lo que tengo que hacer es:
Indique el código que me devolverá quien gastó más dinero sin utilizar "Total de factura".

Intenté esto:
`` SELECT facturas.CodigoDeCliente, facturas.NombreDeCliente, SUM(`detalle de factura`.`SubtotalDelArticulo`) AS Gasto FROM `detalle de factura`  INNER JOIN facturas ON `detalle de factura`.`NumeroDeFactura` = facturas.NumeroDeFactura GROUP BY NombreDeCliente ORDER BY Gasto DESC; ``

El problema es que en el caso de "Gomez" y "Perez" devuelve 990 porque tienen el mismo NúmeroDeFactura. Lo que yo necesito es que en el caso de Gomez en la columna de la suma devuelva 550 y en el de Perez 440.

Comment: No puedo cambiar los datos de las tablas, es decir que no puedo cambiar el número de factura de Gomez a 102, por ejemplo

Comment: Ahí falta una tabla que relaciona `facturas` y  `clientes`. ¿Esa tabla no existe?

Comment: Agrupa también por sucursal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que tienes que conectar esas tablas por DOS campos, porque parece ser que cada sucursal tiene su propia numeración de las facturas. Una vez hecho esto, ya puedes agrupar por cliente sin que se te mezclen los importes por coincidir los números de factura:

```
SELECT
  facturas.CodigoDeCliente,
  facturas.NombreDeCliente,
  SUM(`detalle de factura`.`SubtotalDelArticulo`) AS Gasto
FROM `detalle de factura`
  INNER JOIN facturas
    ON `detalle de factura`.`NumeroDeFactura` = facturas.NumeroDeFactura
    AND `detalle de factura`.Sucursal = facturas.Sucursal
GROUP BY NombreDeCliente
ORDER BY Gasto DESC;
```